# Rowwise name of first and last columns for every run of 1

Tags: r

I have a data frame where there a several columns with prefix `col`:

```
df <- data.frame(row_id = c(100, 101, 102, 103, 104, 105, 106, 107, 108, 109),
             col1 = c(1,0,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,0),
             col2 = c(1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,0,0),
             col3 = c(0,0,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,0),
             col4 = c(1,1,1,0,0,1,0,1,1,1),
             col5 = c(1,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,1))
```

I want to be able to create a separate table where the first column is row_id, and for every row, I want to get the names of the first and last column for every run of 1. For example, the output for `row_id = 100` would be:

```
| row_id | first_col | last_col |
| 100    | col1      | col2     |
| 100    | col4      | col5     |
```

I'll need to apply this method to a much larger data frame, about a thousand columns per row, so any help on that would be much appreaciated.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove `if (.N > 1)` to include length-1 "run"s

```r
df <- data.frame(row_id = c(100, 101, 102, 103, 104, 105, 106, 107, 108, 109),
             col1 = c(1,0,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,0),
             col2 = c(1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,0,0),
             col3 = c(0,0,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,0),
             col4 = c(1,1,1,0,0,1,0,1,1,1),
             col5 = c(1,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,1))

library(data.table)
library(magrittr)

setDT(df) %>% 
  melt('row_id') %>% 
  .[, rid := rleid(value), keyby = row_id] %>% 
  .[value == 1, 
      if (.N > 1)
      .(first_col = first(variable), 
        last_col = last(variable)),
   by = .(row_id, rid)] %>% 
  .[, -'rid']
#>    row_id first_col last_col
#> 1:    100      col1     col2
#> 2:    100      col4     col5
#> 3:    101      col4     col5
#> 4:    102      col1     col4
#> 5:    105      col2     col4
#> 6:    106      col2     col3
#> 7:    107      col1     col4
#> 8:    108      col3     col4
#> 9:    109      col4     col5
```

<sup>Created on 2021-11-24 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: I keep getting "Error in `[.data.frame`(., , `:=`(rid, rleid(value)), keyby = row_id) :  unused argument (keyby = row_id)" when running the code, not sure why?

Comment: You have to load the data.table and magrittr libraries for this code to work (and install them with install.packages if it’s not yet installed)